How to integrate atomic wave-functions in Cartesian coordinates?
I tried to integrate square of (real valued) wavefunction ψ^2 over 3D space for 6p_x orbital of an atom in Cartesian coordinates. I could not get the value of 1 which was expected from a normalized wavefunction. I tried several integration methods for NIntegrate function (not shown below). None of them worked.
I'm attaching the notebook file and kernel init file (which was used for a short notation I used in the code).
Similar method is to be used for calculating overlap integral of wavefunctions of neighboring atoms in further calculations. I want to know if these integrals are valid for such calculations. Please let me know if I'm missing anything.
Thanks!
Wolfram Notebook
Kernel Init file

Welcome to this forum! Your post should be self-contained. Please, avoid external links, there could be viruses.

It looks like SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] is not normalized as expected. For example, we define hydrogen wave function as follows
a0 = Quantity["BohrRadius"]/Quantity["Meters"];

\[Psi][{n_, l_, m_}, {r_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_}] := 
  With[{\[Rho] = 2 r/(n a0)}, 
   Sqrt[(2/(n a0))^3 (n - l - 1)!/(2 n (n + l)!)]
     Exp[-\[Rho]/2] \[Rho]^
    l LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, \[Rho]] SphericalHarmonicY[l, 
     m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]];

Then we try to compute
Integrate[
 Abs[\[Psi][{6, 1, -1}, {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}]]^2 r^2, {r, 0, 
  Infinity}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}]

Out[]= 1.17809725

As we can see it is not normalized on unit. Also, let define as in your notebook
\[CapitalPsi]6px = 
  1/Sqrt[2] (\[Psi][{6, 1, -1}, {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}] - \[Psi][{6, 1,
        1}, {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}]);

Then we have
Integrate[
 Abs[\[CapitalPsi]6px]^2 r^2, {r, 0, Infinity}, {\[Theta], 0, 
  Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}]

Out[]= 1.178097245 

Note, that the radial part of wave function is normalized as expected. Really, let define
R[{n_, l_, m_}, {r_}] := 
 With[{\[Rho] = 2 r/(n a0)}, 
  Sqrt[(2/(n a0))^3 (n - l - 1)!/(2 n (n + l)!)]
    Exp[-\[Rho]/2] \[Rho]^l LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, \[Rho]]]

Now we have for example
Integrate[Abs[R[{6, 1, -1}, {r}]]^2 r^2, {r, 0, Infinity}]

Out[]= 1.00000000

To transform wave function to Cartesian coordinates we use
rule = {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], \[Theta] -> 
    ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], \[Phi] -> ArcTan[x, y]};

With this rule we can visualize wave function as follows
DensityPlot[
 Abs[\[CapitalPsi]6px]^2 /. rule /. z -> 0, {x, -5 a0, 
  5 a0}, {y, -5 a0, 5 a0}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]


At large scale we can use logarithm to visualize wave function as follows
DensityPlot[
 Log@(1 + Abs[\[CapitalPsi]6px]^2 /. rule /. z -> 0), {x, -300 a0, 
  300 a0}, {y, -300 a0, 300 a0}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]


To integrate wave function in the Cartesian coordinates we use module
int[s_] := 
 Module[{a0 = 
    Rationalize[Quantity["BohrRadius"]/Quantity["Meters"], 10^-100], 
   Phi6px}, L = s a0;
  \[Psi][{n_, l_, m_}, {r_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_}] := 
   With[{\[Rho] = 2 r/(n a0)}, 
    Sqrt[(2/(n a0))^3 (n - l - 1)!/(2 n (n + l)!)]
      Exp[-\[Rho]/2] \[Rho]^
     l LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, \[Rho]] SphericalHarmonicY[l, 
      m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]; 
  rule = {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], \[Theta] -> 
     ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], \[Phi] -> ArcTan[x, y]};
  Phi6px = 
   1/Sqrt[2] (\[Psi][{6, 1, -1}, {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}] - \[Psi][{6, 
         1, 1}, {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}]) /. rule; 
  NIntegrate[Abs[Phi6px]^2, {x, -L , L}, {y, -L , L}, {z, -L, L}, 
    Method -> "QuasiMonteCarlo"]] 

Example of usage
int[87] // Quiet

Out[]= 1.00069

This is probably the best what we can compute with this numerical method. Note that exact answer shown above is 1.178097245. This is also not 1 due to exotic normalization of SphericalHarmonicY used in Mathematica. Therefore, numerical integration has large error compared to 1.178.

Thanks for the answer. I just noticed a typo in my original Mathematica file. I realized that while reading your answer. I had cubed the denominator of my normalizing factor. Now I'm getting correct value of the integral.
